# LinQ: return the last or higher value for each distinct other element

Tags: linq

Let says I have this table in my database

```
Region | ApplicationDate | Value
-------|-----------------|------
US     | 2016-12-01      | 14
UK     | 2016-12-01      | 20
US     | 2016-11-15      | 12
UK     | 2016-10-01      | 25
AU     | 2016-09-01      | 150
AU     | 2016-08-01      | 100
US     | 2016-08-01      | 11
US     | 2016-02-01      | 10
UK     | 2016-01-01      | 30
```

What is the query (LinQ) that will return the last value for each region

```
US     | 2016-12-01      | 14
UK     | 2016-12-01      | 20
AU     | 2016-09-01      | 150
```

Comment: Did you try anything at all ? It just looks like simple `Order By` and `Group By`.

Comment: Start with `GroupBy`. When in stuck again - come and modify your question to contain your best attempt.

Comment: last value based on what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need the last item in each category, the strategy for making LINQ query is as follows:

- **Group by the category** - in your case, that's `Region`
- **Sort inside each group** - you need to order by date, descending
- **Take the item that you need** - use `First` inside `Select`.

The query looks as follows:

```
var res = data
    .GroupBy(item => item.Region)
    .ToDictionary(
        g => g.Key
    ,   g => g.OrderByDescending(item => item.Applicationdate).First().Value
    );
```